# Akka Future threads are never released

Tags: java, multithreading, akka

I am trying to perform some heavy computations in parallel. For this I use Akka (in Java).

Instead of defining actors, I wrap my computations into a Future, as suggested by the documentation.

The computations are correctly performed in parallel but the problem is that the threads opened for the `Future<>` are never closed and at some point I reach an error: `OutOfMemory: unable to create new native thread`

My code structure looks like this:

```
public void compute(){
    for(Attribute attribute : attributes){
        computeAttribute(attribute);
    }
}

private void computeAttribute(Attribute attribute){
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("System");
    int nb = findNumberOfIterations(attribute);

    List<Future<AttributeResult>> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Computation to be performed in parallel
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        // MasterCaller contains the heavy computation logic
        Future<AttributeResult> f = Futures.future(new MasterCaller(attribute, i), system.dispatcher());
        answers.add(f);
    }

    Future<Iterable<AttributeResult>> futures = Futures.sequence(answers, system.dispatcher());

    Future<AttributeResult> futureTotal = futures.map(new MasterMapper(), system.dispatcher());

    try {
        // Additional processing step after all resulted have been computed
        AttributeResult value = Await.result(futureTotal, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        postProcess(value, attribute);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Let's say that about 10 threads are created each time `computeAttribute()` is called. Then if there are 1000 elements in the `attributes` list, the code will keep creating 10 000 active threads !

I would really appreciate getting some help on this since this problem makes the usage of Akka and the parallel computation impossible.

Comment: What prevents the code from trying to create all those threads right away? Whether or not the threads are released, if you don't have bounds on the number of threads that are being created, I would expect the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new ActorSystem for every invocation of `computeAttribute` and you never shut it down. Since you don't use anything in Akka, I'd recommend that your `computeAttribute`-method takes a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` as a parameter and then you can pass in either one you've created yourself via `ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService` or `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor` (you'll still need to shut them down at an opportune point in time) or pass in `ExecutionContext.global()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Indeed shutting down the ActorSystem at the end of the function does the trick but results in bad performances. So I will go for the solution you are suggesting.